# QTreeView dynamic height according to content, disclosure triangle

Tags: python, pyside2, qtreeview, qtreewidget

I want to emulate a [disclosure triangle / disclosure widget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclosure_widget) with `QTreeWidget`. For that, I created a `QTreeWidget` with only one top level item. Its background is transparent, its header is invisible.

[image: Collapsed]
[image: Expanded]

Here is the code (mwe):

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import ( QApplication,
                                QLabel,
                                QTreeWidget,
                                QTreeWidgetItem, 
                                QVBoxLayout,
                                QWidget)


class DisclosureTree(QTreeWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        # Add content
        self.setColumnCount(1)
        parent_item = QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['Disclosure triangle'])
        self.addTopLevelItem(parent_item)
        parent_item.addChild(QTreeWidgetItem(parent_item, 'AAA'))
        parent_item.addChild(QTreeWidgetItem(parent_item, 'BBB'))
        parent_item.addChild(QTreeWidgetItem(parent_item, 'CCC'))

        # Cosmetics
        self.header().hide()
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: transparent;')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    disclosuretree = DisclosureTree()
    label = QLabel('Plenty of space above…')
    vbox.addWidget(disclosuretree)
    vbox.addWidget(label)
    vbox.addStretch()

    widget = QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(vbox)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that I want the widget height to automatically resize whether it is collapsed or expanded, like here for example:

[image]

Does anybody know how to do that? Thanks a lot and let me know if I can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update the maximum height of the widget, based on its contents. For each top item you need to get the height for that row using [`rowHeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#rowHeight) and do the same recursively for child items whenever the item is expanded. Also, you need to overwrite the `sizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint`.

```py
class DisclosureTree(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.expanded.connect(self.updateHeight)
        self.collapsed.connect(self.updateHeight)

    def updateHeight(self):
        self.setMaximumHeight(self.sizeHint().height())

    def getHeight(self, parent=None):
        height = 0
        if not parent:
            parent = self.rootIndex()
        for row in range(self.model().rowCount(parent)):
            child = self.model().index(row, 0, parent)
            height += self.rowHeight(child)
            if self.isExpanded(child) and self.model().hasChildren(child):
                    height += self.getHeight(child)
        return height

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        hint.setHeight(self.getHeight() + self.frameWidth() * 2)
        return hint

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()
```